# ansible include_vars ordering issue

Tags: ansible

```
#file: cmservers.yml

 - hosts: cmservers
   tasks:
     - include_vars: /var/cm/local/ansible/vars/cmusers.yml
     - debug: var=users
   roles:
     - ansible-users-master
```

I am finding that the roles tasks are being executed first, however the users list needs to be defined first, which is not happening.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Create a role with the `include` and `debug` in it so you can have all `roles` at the same level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pre_tasks` to make sure that some tasks are executed before role and `post_tasks` to make sure that some tasks are executed after the role is applied. So changing your `tasks` to `pre_tasks` will fix the problem.

```
- hosts: cmservers

  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: /var/cm/local/ansible/vars/cmusers.yml
    - debug: var=users

  roles:
    - ansible-users-master
```

You can check the [role documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html) for further details.

Comment: That did the trick. Brilliant. Now my variables are defined. Now there are in fact two include files containing vars which I am including. I have set the Merge flag in ansible hash_behaviuor  yet the last loaded include file is overriding the users hash value.

Comment: @SebastienHadjifotis I'm not much familiar with `hash_behaviour` but there might be a bug as described here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10446. Not sure whether you are running into the same issue.

Comment: It looks like the same issue. I added a comment to that post. I do hope there is resolution. As I need to have the capability to merge hash's.

Comment: found a solution to avoid merging was to define separate hash names and then specify the role with passing the name of the hash `  roles:
   - {role: ansible-users-master, users: "{{ cmusers }}", groups: "{{ cmusers_groups }}"}
   - {role: ansible-users-master, users: "{{ appusers }}", groups: "{{ appusers_groups }}"}`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use `vars_files` directive in the playbook. This comes handy when you store your variables in a role `vars/main.yml`, but there are some additional variables, or some private data (you might use Ansible Vault for that) to include while executing playbook.

```
#file: cmservers.yml

 - hosts: cmservers
   vars_files:
     - /var/cm/local/ansible/vars/cmusers.yml
   roles:
     - ansible-users-master
```

Since `include_vars` is a task it's better to use it in roles/hanlders and use `vars_files` in playbooks instead. It is also easier to pass Ansible command line variables with `vars_files`. For further info see: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html

Comment: totally agree. this is a better answer even though pre_tasks are noteworthy.